# Using groupby to operate only on rows that have the same value for one of the columns pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

How do I create groupby function that only completes an operation on a subset of rows where the column has the same value?

So in the table below, I want to subset the rows based on the same doclist and then add NP and Pr for only that subset of doclists for column "organization".

```
        Organization NP Pr
    0    doclist[0]  0   0
    1    doclist[0]  1   0
    4    doclist[1]  1   0
    5    doclist[4]  1   0
    6    doclist[4]  0   1
```

want below using .apply() - or is there a better/more efficient way?

```
        Organization NP Pr  Sum
    0    doclist[0]  0   0   1
    1    doclist[0]  1   0   1
    4    doclist[1]  1   0   1
    5    doclist[4]  1   0   2
    6    doclist[4]  0   1   2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a more efficient way, (and you could write this much more readably) but you could always do something like:

```
import pandas as pd

org = ['doclist[0]', 'doclist[0]', 'doclist[1]', 'doclist[4]', 'doclist[4]']
np = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
pr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Organization':org, 'NP':np, 'Pr':pr})

# Make a "lookup" dataframe of the sums for each category
# (Both the "NP" and "Pr" colums of "sums" will contain the result)
sums = df.groupby('Organization').agg(lambda x: x['NP'].sum() + x['Pr'].sum())

# Lookup the result based on the contents of the "Organization" row
df['Sum'] = df.apply(lambda row: sums.ix[row['Organization']]['NP'], axis=1)
```

---

That's rather unreadable, so it might be a bit clearer to write it this way:

```
import pandas as pd

org = ['doclist[0]', 'doclist[0]', 'doclist[1]', 'doclist[4]', 'doclist[4]']
np = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
pr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Organization':org, 'NP':np, 'Pr':pr})

# Make a "lookup" dataframe of the sums for each category
lookup = df.groupby('Organization').agg(lambda x: x['NP'].sum() + x['Pr'].sum())

# Lookup the result based on the contents of the "Organization" row
# The "lookup" dataframe will have the relevant sum in _both_ "NP" and "Pr"
def func(row):
    org = row['Organization']
    group_sum = lookup.ix[org]['NP']
    return group_sum
df['Sum'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

Incidentally, @DSM's looks like a much better way to do this.

Comment: This is great. thanks! Could you explain the last line a bit more?

Answer (score 4):

You want to look at `groupby`, I think -- that's the "operate only on rows that have the same value for one of the columns" part -- and since it looks like you want each row to get the appropriate sum, I think you want to call `.transform` on that.  `transform` "broadcasts" the grouped values up to the full dataframe.

```
df["Sum"] = (df["NP"] + df["Pr"]).groupby(df["Organization"]).transform("sum")
```

For example:

```
>>> df
  Organization  NP  Pr
0   doclist[0]   0   0
1   doclist[0]   1   0
4   doclist[1]   1   0
5   doclist[4]   1   0
6   doclist[4]   0   1

[5 rows x 3 columns]
>>> df["Sum"] = (df["NP"] + df["Pr"]).groupby(df["Organization"]).transform("sum")
>>> df
  Organization  NP  Pr  Sum
0   doclist[0]   0   0    1
1   doclist[0]   1   0    1
4   doclist[1]   1   0    1
5   doclist[4]   1   0    2
6   doclist[4]   0   1    2

[5 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Quite nice! I didn't even know `transform` existed! (Still learning `pandas`. I'm late to the game.)

Comment: @user3314418: always possible I missed something, but you'll need to give an example where it fails.  If you edit a small example where you get the wrong answer -- and the answer you expected -- into your original question I can have a look.

Comment: Thanks again! I'm messing around with it a bit, and I'll post something soon.

Comment: I couldn't get it right with this code, but I was able to modify the other answerer's code correctly. I've pasted an example of where it fails